# Immigration test for a cautious society

Tags: society, alternate-reality

Suppose there's a modern society which has one simple rule to immigration: Pass one test, and you're let in. Fail, and you're rejected. The society is primarily science-based and rather cautious of letting terrorists and serial killers into their country. Optimally, this test would be able to be taken without human interaction. My questions are:

- What would this test look like? (As in, what ideas should it encompass to keep unwanted people out, based on current immigration systems?)
- What would the advantages be for having this single-test system? (besides simplicity)

Comment: I don't have time for the full answer this question is due, but I'll give you one nudge: the test would be LONG.  Like hours and hours long, by design.  To weed out people who have undesirable traits and leanings you would need to wear down their resistance to answering questions in a deceitful manner, and studies have shown people over long periods tend to start answering with their first instinct.  You would also use a lot of indirect questions - eg. you won't ask "do you murder people", but over 50 questions you might probe to see whether the test taker is capable of sympathy.

Comment: Assuming current technology?

Comment: @GrinningX - over 50 questions you might get to determine how well a person is capable of faking sympathy just as easily as someone who genuinely does.  How would you ensure a person is answering questions genuinely?

Comment: Is there a (preferably world building) motivation behind a one-test system? Most "scientific" societies would hold that a single test is gameable by bad actors, and so a diversity of signals is ideal. You also run up against false positives: prejudging those who should pass but don't. Right now this reads like a thinly veiled politics question that belongs on a other forum.

Comment: @NathanielFord This is a world-building question, the story requires a single-test system to let characters "game" the system. However, it ought to be complicated enough that gaming it could disregarded as unreasonable.

Comment: [Politics](http://politics.stackexchange.com/) leaps to mind, though you'd have to phrase differently, according to their community guidelines.

Comment: Although I agree that most answers to this will primarily be opinion based, that does not mean that good objective answers do not exist.  My critique to that rule is that it inhibits discussion on topics that perhaps need to be discussed and I feel that this site and others like it should be more tolerant in that regard - allow issues that are close to public failings to be discussed publicly, as long as the conversation remains focused on the issue.  The best answers will not always get voted up, but the folks who are looking for the best answers will still be able to find them.

Comment: @Twelfth - While test length is not a guarantee that questions will be answered honestly, it helps a lot. It takes more mental effort to lie than it does to tell the truth, and over time people start taking "the easy way" out.  That's why personality tests are so long.  You can also use test length to develop markers that indicate when someone is taking too long to answer (to spot if they always lie about questions of one type), or force them to answer each question within a short period of time so they don't have time to weigh out what they think the test grader will want to see.

Comment: A persons subconscious mind does not tend to lie, so if you can put them in a senario where they are basically taking the test whille asleep, that would be best. It would be simillar to the faction tests in "Divergent".

Answer (score 1):

So there are two main problems:

- people who are planning to do harm when they enter
- those who might latter become radicalized (changed to want to do
  harm)

The second set is very hard to detect because you essentially are trying to predict the future thoughts of a person, which has never been done reliably.

You would like to test for both, so you must ask questions that will work even if the subject lies and probe for unconscious mind sets that might lead to radicalization.  A very important point is with either it is very likely to get false positives.

If the test is clearly a test then people can lie about their intentions and people who don't yet intend to do harm will pass right through.

Here are three factors that might help:

- The first and best option is a **test that is not obviously a test**,
  or appears to be a test about something else.  A friend from the old
  country that you happen to meet that talks about his beliefs.  A test
  of the local language that subtly probes word associations.  This
  lets you ask about a persons mind set without having to deal with
  them lying.
- Second would be **length**, get a test that goes over a long time to 
  ware down liars and get as much information about the subject as
  possible.
- Third you can also focus on **unconscious or hard to manipulate

  signals** (heart rate sweat breathing pattern) the problem with all
  of these is they only detect stress which could result from worrying 
  about not being allowed in(normal) or worrying about being
  caught(what you are trying to detect)

Edit: 
As Ethan Chapman pointed out, since the second type could include people already in the country at the time the test is implemented, for completeness the test would have to be run on all residents of the country. This significantly raises the cost.

Comment: Isn't it somewhat pointless to make a large point of testing for the second kind, as the current inhabitants could just as easily become radicalized and there are (presumably) far more of them?

Comment: @EthanChapman good point incorporating

Comment: Your first factor could be more useful than it seems - a test that *appears to be about something else* can usefully misdirect, to rule out those who just repeat or try to guess the winning answer.  So if they come up with a test slanted to, say, obedience, when they're really testing for something *else* (compassion, or ethics or such) - those trying to game the test will be focused in the completely wrong direction, and those who ignore the slant in their answers should really believe them, to go against the grain.  It will test against ordinary follower-types, but that might be a positive.